# How to find a WACOM tablet screen?

Tags: c#, wacom

I trying to fill Wacom tablet screen with my application. How can I find this screen working area?

At this moment I just trying to find this screen by Device Friendly name using ScreenInterrogatory class (code below), but it requires me to know device name. I looking for a way to do this for any Wacom device without knowing the device name (using Wintab api).

```
//
public Screen GetWacomWorkingArea(string wacomDeviceName)
{
    foreach(var screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        if(screen.DeviceFriendlyName == wacomDeviceName)
        {
             return screen.WorkingArea;
        }
    }
}
//

public static class ScreenInterrogatory
{
    public const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;

    #region enums

    public enum QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS : uint
    {
        QDC_ALL_PATHS = 0x00000001,
        QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS = 0x00000002,
        QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT = 0x00000004
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_OTHER = 0xFFFFFFFF,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_HD15 = 0,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SVIDEO = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_COMPOSITE_VIDEO = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_COMPONENT_VIDEO = 3,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DVI = 4,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_HDMI = 5,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_LVDS = 6,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_D_JPN = 8,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SDI = 9,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL = 10,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED = 11,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_UDI_EXTERNAL = 12,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_UDI_EMBEDDED = 13,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_SDTVDONGLE = 14,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_MIRACAST = 15,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_INTERNAL = 0x80000000,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_UNSPECIFIED = 0,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_PROGRESSIVE = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED_UPPERFIELDFIRST = DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_INTERLACED_LOWERFIELDFIRST = 3,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_IDENTITY = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE90 = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE180 = 3,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_ROTATE270 = 4,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_IDENTITY = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CENTERED = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_STRETCHED = 3,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_ASPECTRATIOCENTEREDMAX = 4,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CUSTOM = 5,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_PREFERRED = 128,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_8BPP = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_16BPP = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_24BPP = 3,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_32BPP = 4,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_NONGDI = 5,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xffffffff
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_SOURCE = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    public enum DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE : uint
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME = 1,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME = 2,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_PREFERRED_MODE = 3,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_ADAPTER_NAME = 4,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_SET_TARGET_PERSISTENCE = 5,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_BASE_TYPE = 6,
        DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    #endregion

    #region structs

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        public uint LowPart;
        public int HighPart;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO
    {
        public LUID adapterId;
        public uint id;
        public uint modeInfoIdx;
        public uint statusFlags;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO
    {
        public LUID adapterId;
        public uint id;
        public uint modeInfoIdx;
        private DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY outputTechnology;
        private DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION rotation;
        private DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING scaling;
        private DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL refreshRate;
        private DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING scanLineOrdering;
        public bool targetAvailable;
        public uint statusFlags;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL
    {
        public uint Numerator;
        public uint Denominator;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO
    {
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO sourceInfo;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO targetInfo;
        public uint flags;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION
    {
        public uint cx;
        public uint cy;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO
    {
        public ulong pixelRate;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL hSyncFreq;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL vSyncFreq;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION activeSize;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION totalSize;
        public uint videoStandard;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING scanLineOrdering;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE
    {
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO targetVideoSignalInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINTL
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE
    {
        public uint width;
        public uint height;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT pixelFormat;
        public POINTL position;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_UNION
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE targetMode;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE sourceMode;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO
    {
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE infoType;
        public uint id;
        public LUID adapterId;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_UNION modeInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS
    {
        public uint value;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER
    {
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE type;
        public uint size;
        public LUID adapterId;
        public uint id;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME
    {
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER header;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS flags;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY outputTechnology;
        public ushort edidManufactureId;
        public ushort edidProductCodeId;
        public uint connectorInstance;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        public string monitorFriendlyDeviceName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string monitorDevicePath;
    }

    #endregion

    #region DLL-Imports

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(
        QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS flags, out uint numPathArrayElements, out uint numModeInfoArrayElements);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(
        QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS flags,
        ref uint numPathArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] PathInfoArray,
        ref uint numModeInfoArrayElements, [Out] DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] ModeInfoArray,
        IntPtr currentTopologyId
        );

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME deviceName);

    #endregion

    private static string MonitorFriendlyName(LUID adapterId, uint targetId)
    {
        var deviceName = new DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME
        {
            header =
            {
                size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME)),
                adapterId = adapterId,
                id = targetId,
                type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_TYPE.DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME
            }
        };
        var error = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref deviceName);
        if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
        return deviceName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames()
    {
        uint pathCount, modeCount;
        var error = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, out pathCount, out modeCount);
        if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw new Win32Exception(error);

        var displayPaths = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[pathCount];
        var displayModes = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[modeCount];
        error = QueryDisplayConfig(QUERY_DEVICE_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS,
            ref pathCount, displayPaths, ref modeCount, displayModes, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw new Win32Exception(error);

        for (var i = 0; i < modeCount; i++)
            if (displayModes[i].infoType == DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE.DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET)
                yield return MonitorFriendlyName(displayModes[i].adapterId, displayModes[i].id);
    }

    public static string DeviceFriendlyName(this Screen screen)
    {
        var allFriendlyNames = GetAllMonitorsFriendlyNames();
        for (var index = 0; index < Screen.AllScreens.Length; index++)
            if (Equals(screen, Screen.AllScreens[index]))
                return allFriendlyNames.ToArray()[index];
        return null;
    }

}
```